# Why does the height of the xct:TabView change when returning to a page with HasNavigationBar="false"

Tags: xamarin, navigationbar, tabview, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am facing an issue with the TabView from the XamarinCommunityToolkit.

There is a MainPage with two tabs "A" and "B", "A" showing some content, "B" serving as navigation to another ContentPage "DetailsPage". Additionally, the MainPage has set NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" and should not display any navigation bar.

On launch, the navigation bar is not visible as expected. When clicking Tab "B" and then the back button on the "DetailsPage", the TabView seems to change its height and takes additional space.

Here is basically all of the code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
             >
    <StackLayout>
        <views:TabView 
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            BackgroundColor="Gold"
            TabStripHeight="60"
            TabStripBackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
            >
            <views:TabViewItem
                Text="A">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Cyan"/>
            </views:TabViewItem>
            <views:TabViewItem
                Text="B"
                TabTapped="ShowDetailsPage">
            </views:TabViewItem>
        </views:TabView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In the code-behind file App.xaml.cs one additional line is added in order to enable navigating to the "DetailsPage":

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Here is the result with the undesired "golden bar":
[Undesired change in height of TabView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE1Am.png)

I already tried to:

- Set NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); in the constructor of the MainPage instead
- Set NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); in the OnAppearing event instead

Any help or hints are highly appreciated.

**EDIT/ADDITION:**
The hint towards *wrong layout of the tabview* as mentioned by Alexander May lets us narrow down the issue even further.

The issue exists also when navigating to a details page via any navigation object such as a button within the content of the TabViewItem.

The sample can thus be further reduced to one single tab:

```
    <StackLayout>
        <views:TabView 
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            BackgroundColor="Gold"
            TabStripHeight="60"
            TabStripBackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
            >
            <views:TabViewItem
                Text="A">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Cyan">
                    <Button Clicked="ShowDetailsPage" Text="Click Me" BackgroundColor="LightPink"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </views:TabViewItem>
        </views:TabView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open bug for this on the Community Toolkit site: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/625

Answer (score 0):

The undesired "golden bar" is due to the wrong layout of the tabview,please try my solution which works well!

Below is the Code in **xaml**:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:views="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
         x:Class="AppNavTab.MainPage"
         >
<Grid>
    <views:TabView
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            TabStripBackgroundColor="Green"
            TabStripHeight="60"
            TabContentBackgroundColor="Cyan">

        <views:TabViewItem
                Text="A"
                TextColor="Black"
                FontSize="12">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Cyan">
                <Label
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="TabContent1" />
            </Grid>
        </views:TabViewItem>

        <views:TabViewItem
                Text="B"
                TextColor="Black"
                FontSize="12"
                TabTapped="TabViewItem_TabTapped">
       
        </views:TabViewItem>
    </views:TabView>
</Grid>
```

Below is the code behind xaml:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
       }

        private void TabViewItem_TabTapped(object sender, Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.TabTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
        }
    }
```

Workaround 2:

```
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" x:Name="grid" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Cyan" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        
    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="item1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="Button_Clicked1"/>
    <Button Text="item2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked2"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Tab "B" should not have own TabViewItem Content but only act as navigation item to the details page. Your suggestion thus changes the behaviour and does not solve the issue. Removing the Grid + Label from your Tab "B" also shows the same undesired stripe. Still, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hi P,I have edited my solution and now the Tab "B" only act as a Navigation Page when Tapping on it.Hope this resolves your problem!

Comment: Hi Alex, you are using the same color CYAN for both the TabContentBackgroundColor of the TabView as well as the BackgroundColor of the Grid within TabViewItem "A" and thus the undesired bar is not visible, but still persists. Your answer does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi P,1.The bottom tab of tabview is designed to switch between bottom tab pages instead of pushing to another page.2.Per official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview, there is not tapped event in the tabitem.3.As a workaround,I suggest you can take another workaround that I provided.